# Call ListItem Present in BulletedList in CS file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

net

I have the following BulletedList in my aspx file

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="DocumentList" runat="server" 
DisplayMode="LinkButton" onclick="DocumentList_Click">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Documents/testpage.pdf" Text="testpage.pdf" >test page</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Documents/testpage2.pdf" Text="testpage2.pdf">test page 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

What I want to do is in my CS file, I would like to assing the below

```
Sting filepath = // here i want to get the ListItem Value
Sting filename = // here i want to get the file name present in Listitem text.
```

How do i get the above two values in the below button click event.

```
protected void DocumentList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void DocumentList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
     ListItem li = DocumentList.Items[e.Index];
     Sting filepath = li.Value;
     Sting filename = li.Text;

}
```

But you don't need To specify text field to hold value of file name, you can get it from path.

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="DocumentList" runat="server" 
DisplayMode="LinkButton" onclick="DocumentList_Click">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Documents/testpage.pdf" >test page</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Documents/testpage2.pdf" >test page 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

then

```
protected void DocumentList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
     ListItem li = DocumentList.Items[e.Index];
     Sting filepath = li.Value;
     Sting filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(li.Value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DocumentList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    var item = DocumentList.Items[e.Index];
    String filepath = item.Value;
    String filename = item.Text;
}
```